# Select rows that have a particular string in column A but not in column X, Y, or Z in R

Tags: r, filter, subset

I have a data frame that I would like to subset based on two conditions. The first is that I would like to select for rows that have a string "A" in column 5. The second is that I want to make sure these rows do not have the string "Y" in columns 6 to 50.

I am able to easily select for the first condition but having trouble with the second.

```
# example input (data)

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ETC TO 50
X X X X A Z Z Z Z 
X X X X A A Z Z Z
X X X X A Z Y Y Z
X X X X B X A Z Z
X X X X A Z Y B X
```

```
# example output (data2)

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ETC TO 50
X X X X A Z Z Z Z 
X X X X A A Z Z Z
```

```
# code I have tried

data2 <- data[data$`5` == "A" & data[,6:50] != "Y", ]
```

Comment: `data[data$\`5\` == 'A' & !rowSums(data[,6:50]=='Y'),]`

Comment: Could you provide code to make a reproducible example dataset please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you could use `filter`

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% filter(`5` == "A") %>% filter_at(6:50, all_vars(. != "Y"))
```

Or in base R :

```
data[data$`5` == "A" & rowSums(data[6:50] == "Y") == 0, ]
```